# Troubles with LOAD DATA INFILE and max_binlog_cache_size

Tags: mysql, download

I have problems with importing the data into MySQL database.
I've 2 files (5 gb each one) to be imported to MySQL database.

When I code `LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/user/user/desktop/airac.so-' INTO airac01 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' ' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'`; I have the following error:

```
Multi-statement transaction required more than 'max_binlog_cache_size' bytes of storage; increase this mysql variable and try again.
```

I tried to find it in my.ini file to increase but I did not find it.
Do any one know what to do in such situation? is there is a way to split the load file or to increase the `max_binlog_cache_size` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, you have to change it for both the client and the daemon mysqld server. Change the `my.cnf` or `my.ini` file under the `[mysqld]` section and set `max_binlog_cache_size=10000M` or you could run these commands in a MySQL console connected to that same server:

```
set global net_buffer_length=10000000000; 
set global max_binlog_cache_size=10000000000;
```

Use a very large value for the packet size, because they are in bytes and then restart your MySQL server.